# Microsoft Botframework integration with slack Unauthorized using REST API

Tags: rest, botframework, slack

It appears that in the past week something has changed in the way the Microsoft bot framework connects to Slack, and the result is that messages my server sends to the botframework to be published in a slack channel are rejected with a 401 unauthorized error. I created a new bot account on Friday and walked through the setup process to install the bot on a slack channel and the botframework does post data to my server when messages are sent on a slack channel where the bot is an added user, however any response my server tries to send fails with the unauthorized error.

When using the same bot in Microsoft Teams the responses go through successfully, so this appears to be slack-specific (although I haven't tried all of the channels).

I am able to successfully get the OAuth token needed to make the request from my server to the bot framework using the tutorial outlined here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/08/19/build-skype-bot-with-microsoft-bot-framework-oauth-and-rest-api/ (with the endpoints updated based on the API changes in July).

This issue began sometime between September 6th and 8th, as we were able to successfully send messages from our server to the bot framework and have them relayed to the slack channel on the 6th, but when we tried again on the 8th we first saw the unauthorized error.

An example URL that we use to send a response from our server to the botframework is:

https://slack.botframework.com/v3/conversations/B71AHEC90%3AT1QUNVBGF%3AC3UV1QG2G/activities/fa4901052dfc4453909e7567ba09c8fe

Comment: I'll look into if others are experiencing the same behavior in slack.  The best thing I can suggest is to double check you end points at this time. Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce this.

Comment: I figured out the issue. It had to do with the scope URL. We were using https://graph.microsoft.com/.default as described [in this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/08/19/build-skype-bot-with-microsoft-bot-framework-oauth-and-rest-api/) as opposed to https://api.botframework.com/.default. Interestingly, the old scopes url did continue to work for teams and skype, so not sure why it worked for msft products but not other chat services.

Comment: glad you got it figured out!